# How to set different inner page log in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, codex

I have purchased wordpress skilled theme for my development i want to know how to set different logo for different pages,

i have used transparent header with logo color white that's why i want to change inner pages logo's.

Link :- www.iihr.edu.in

Answer (score 0):

You can create an widget position for logo & then use Widget Logic plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/